# Transform Uppercase Text to Lowercase, Except for first letter in CSS

Tags: css

Example: Input into the database is "PARROT"

Question: How can I use the text-transform attribute (or something else) to have it displayed as "Parrot"?

```
text-transform: Capitalize
```

The above would only achieve what I want as long as the database input is all lower case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use the `first-letter` pseudo-selector.

```css
div {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

div::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>PARROT</div>
```

Comment: While this works for a single word, `text-transform:capitalize` makes the first letter of every word uppercase. But this is as close as you'll get with nothing but CSS